View with multiple TouchableOpacity is not clickable on the text and TouchableOpacity not clickable correctly if another TouchableOpacity is above it
I have a navigation bar component in react native and it have a dropdown option. Once I click the dropdown 2 options will come as Account & Sign out. All these dropdown, and 2 options are having TouchableOpacity.
The Dropdown TouchableOpacity is working fine. Also the 1st option in the dropdown menu (Account) is also work. But when I to press the Sign Out. This is the sample image and when I press in the nip of the arrow Sign out is pressed.

 return (
<View
  style={[
    dropdownVisible && Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? styles.containerIos
      : styles.container,
  ]}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
    <Image source={bar3} style={{height: 20, width: 20}} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <Image source={app_logo} style={styles.logo} />
  <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
    <Image
      source={
        userImage && userImage.length > 1 ? {uri: userImage} : smilyFace
      }
      style={
        userImage && userImage.length > 1
          ? styles.UserProfile
          : styles.userImage
      }
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleDropdownPress}>
      <Image
        source={dropdownVisible ? arrowUp : arrowDown}
        style={
          dropdownVisible ? styles.dropdownArrowUp : styles.dropdownArrow
        }
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    {dropdownVisible && (
      <View
        style={[
          Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? styles.dropdownIos
            : styles.dropdownOptions,
        ]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => accountPress()}
          hitSlop={{left: 20, top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10}}>
          <Text style={styles.dropdownOptionText}>Account</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => logOutPress()}
          hitSlop={{left: 20, top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10}}>
          <Text style={styles.dropdownOptionText}>Sign out</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )}
  </View>
</View>

);
This is my coding of issue. I have imported TouchableOpacity from react-native Also this is my style sheet.
container: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  alignContent: 'space-between',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: white,
  paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 16 : 16,
  paddingBottom: 16,
  paddingHorizontal: 16,
  width: deviceWidth,
},
containerIos: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  alignContent: 'space-between',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: white,
  paddingVertical: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 16,
  top: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? -10 : 0,
  paddingHorizontal: 16,
  width: deviceWidth,
},
leftContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
},
centerContainer: {
  flex: 2,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
},
rightContainer: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  width: deviceWidth / 6,
  gap: 10,
},
logo: {
  width: 170,
  height: 30,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
  alignSelf: 'center',
  marginLeft: 30,
},
userImage: {
  height: 32,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
  width: 32,
},
UserProfile: {
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  resizeMode: 'cover',
  borderRadius: 15,
},
dropdownArrow: {
  height: 25,
  width: 25,
},
dropdownArrowUp: {
  height: 10,
  width: 15,
},
dropdownOptions: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 40,
  right: 0,
  backgroundColor: white,
  padding: 10,
  borderRadius: 4,
  width: deviceWidth / 2,
  shadowColor: GreyText,
  shadowOpacity: 0.3,
  zIndex: 1,
  elevation: 10,
  shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 2,
  },
  shadowRadius: 3.84,
},
dropdownIos: {
  position: 'static',
  top: 60,
  right: deviceWidth * 0.53,
  backgroundColor: white,
  padding: 10,
  borderRadius: 4,
  width: deviceWidth / 2,
  shadowColor: GreyText,
  shadowOpacity: 0.3,
  zIndex: 1,
  elevation: 10,
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
  },
  shadowRadius: 3.84,
},
dropdownOptionText: {
  color: Black,
  fontSize: FONT_SIZE_16,
  paddingVertical: 4,
},

For your information, I am facing this issue since last week and tried every possible way, read every stackoverflow questions related to this, checked in the github issues, asked AI chats. But still couldn't find a correct solution for this.
If anyone can help me with this it will be very helpful. I am ready to provide any aditional informations. Thank you in advance.

Expecting some valuable recommendations to get rid of this issue.

This might be happening because your drop down option is not taking the full container width, add this to the styles & remove the hitslop on touchables.
this is a gif of your code working with the updates below:

<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.dropdownOptionContainer} // add style to touchable
   onPress={() => accountPress()}
   hitSlop={{left: 20, top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10}}>
   <Text style={styles.dropdownOptionText}>Account</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.dropdownOptionContainer} // add style to touchable
   onPress={() => logOutPress()}
   hitSlop={{left: 20, top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10}}>
   <Text style={styles.dropdownOptionText}>Sign out</Text>
</TouchableOpacity> 

update the styles:
dropdownOptionContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  width: '100%',
},   
  


No. I have tried that but it is not working and it is messing up the whole UI.

its messing up the ui because it doesn't have a fixed width add a width: 300 to the dropdownOptionContainer,
also you need to remove the hitslop from your touchableOpacity on both of them, this is why touching the account might be triggering the signout

I have already tried these. As I mentioned I have already tried all the possible solutions like set up height, width, removing hitslop, changing styles. But still the issue happens.

I added a gif of your code working in the answer I gave above, with the changes I advised, if your'e still having trouble implementing it, you can setup a quick google meet call and ill assist you with resolving
